# Year storage in Date type field

Tags: android

### Android

Can anybody tell can we Insert only "**year**" in Date type field in *SQLite* database in android.

---

Thanks

Comment: At worst case you could store dates all for january first, but in your code just take care of the year of those YYYY-01-01 dates...

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment you could just add a fixed day and month to your dates, ie 01-01, because sqlite does not natively support Date with only a year, [check this documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I am fetching only year from the date and want to store only year in date type field. So is it possible ?

Comment: No you can't, check the doc. If you want to store and retrieve a single Year, that is to say a 4 digits round number, you just need to store it as a simple integer value, not in a _Date_ field.

Comment: I can't store it in date type of filed. I need to store it in int type?

Comment: I understood that you wanted a Date-type field sorry. Yes just use an INTEGER field for this, that will keep for you sorting and other further numeric-processing possibilities.